# Joining 6 mysql tables into one to echo the result into an html table with php

Tags: mysql, merge, html-table

### The purpose of the database

I'm using a mysql database with an Apache server to store homeschool information.  I'm trying to track each assignment similar to a grade book where I can query by subject and month to track scores.

### My database design

**assignment** is the main table and has: id(primary auto inc), student_id, subject_id, points_id, date, Notes_id, and type.

**notes** contains optional notes on the assignment and has id(primary auto inc), note, and date.

**points** has the score and total available for the assignment and contains id(primary auto inc), received, and total.

**student** is a list of students(my children) and contains id(primary auto inc), first_name, and last_name(yes I know this column is pointless since its my kids but I did it for practice).

**subject** is a list of current subjects and contains id(primary auto inc), name, description.  My logic was I can add more subjects pragmatically as needed each year.

**type** is contains the types of assignments and contains id(primary auto inc), name, description.

### Now how do I join to print it out?

I need to join assignment, student, subject, points, notes into one table that I can iterate through with a while loop to echo out recent activity (data entry) into an html table.

I've tried many versions similar to:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM assignment, student, subject, points, notes
                            WHERE assignment.student_id = student.id 
                            AND assignment.subject_id = subject.id 
                            AND assignment.points_id = points.id 
                            ");
```

Doing so has yielded only empty queries.  Can someone nudge me in the right direction?  The end result I'm looking for is a combined table that fills in the stored _id's in assignment with the values I want to display such as: 9/12/2012 Jane Doe Math Quiz 25/28 in an html table.

**Additional info if needed... PHP function storing the data**

```
function submit_entry($con){
    $student = $_POST['student'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $notes = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['notes'],$con);
    $received = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['received'],$con);
    $total = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['total'],$con);
    
    //Retreive student data
    $token = strtok($student, " ");
    $student_firstname = $token;
    $token = strtok(" ");
    $student_lastname = $token;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE first_name='$student_firstname'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $student_id = $row['id'];
    
    //Retrieve subject data
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subject WHERE name='$subject'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $subject_id = $row['id'];
    
    //Retrieve type
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM type WHERE name='$type'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $type_id = $row['id'];
    
    //obtain last inserted ID (assignment)
    if(!mysql_query("INSERT INTO points ( received, total)
    VALUES ('$received', '$total')"))
    {
        die('Error:  ' . mysql_error() . ' in points INSERT!');
    }
    $points_id = mysql_insert_id();
        
    if(!mysql_query("INSERT INTO assignment (student_id, subject_id, type, date, points_id)
    VALUES ('$student_id', '$subject_id', '$type_id', NOW(), '$points_id')"))
    {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error() . ' in assignment INSERT!');
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Is this homework? You could just split it into multiple searches in a php loop that spools it out based off the called id (or all of them). Are you forced to do a join?

Comment: even tho it looks like you copypasted it from homework, thumbs up for proper formatting of first Question ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simi gone with Remm's suggestion.  I'm polling for the values in each table (student, subject, and type) and storing them in an associative array.

```
function recent_activity($count){

$subject_list;
$student_list;
$assignment_type;
$alt_table = false;

//build arrays with keys for echo
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subject");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $subject_list[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $student_list[$row['id']] = $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'];
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM assignment ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $count");
$entry_date = null;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($entry_date != $row['date'])
    {
        if($entry_date == null)
        {
            $entry_date = $row['date'];
            $entry_date_array = date("F j Y", strtotime($row['date']));
            $token = strtok($entry_date_array, " ");
            $token = strtok(" ");
            create_date($token, substr($entry_date_array, 0, 3));
            echo "<table class=\"student-table\">";
            $alt_table = false;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "</table>";
            echo "<div class=\"clear_float\"></div>";
            $entry_date = $row['date'];
            $entry_date_array = date("F j Y", strtotime($row['date']));
            $token = strtok($entry_date_array, " ");
            $token = strtok(" ");
            create_date($token, substr($entry_date_array, 0, 3));
            echo "<table class=\"student-table\">";
            $alt_table = false;
        }
    }

    if($alt_table == true)
    {
        echo "<tr class=\"alt\">";
        $alt_table = false;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        $alt_table = true;
    }

    echo "<td>" . "<a href=\"" . $student_list[$row['student_id']] . "\">" . $student_list[$row['student_id']] . "</a>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $subject_list[$row['subject_id']] . "</td>";
    $row_id = $row['id'];
    $points_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM points WHERE id = '$row_id' ");
    $points_row = mysql_fetch_array($points_result);
    echo "<td>" . $points_row['received'] . " / " . $points_row['total'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
echo "<div class=\"clear_float\"></div>";
}

function create_date($day, $month){
echo "<div class=\"date\">" . "<p>" . $day ."<span>" . $month . "</span>" . "</div>";
}
?>
```

It's still a touch buggy.  I want the tables to be separated by dates with a css created date block inserted infront of each one.  Currently I am getting inaccurately created dates which is the result of an unforeseen problem with the statement

```
if($entry_date != $row['date'])
```

I can see how this project could be misconstrued as homework from the thoroughness of my details.  Being a professional medical machinist programmer/operator has made me appreciate the importance of clearly communicating information.

Comment: Got everything functioning.  Link of it in action at [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIhAGf2qxZM).  @Remm as you can see most definitely not homework  :D  Thanks for the suggestion on unspooling, once I stepped out of trying to force a method for solving my problem a solution presented itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your problem is you are using an `INNER JOIN` on your query, which means records needs to exist in all of the tables.  I suggest using a `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
select *
from assignment a
left join notes n
  on a.notes_id = n.id
left join points p
  on a.points_id = p.id
left join student stu
  on a.student_id = stu.id
left join subject sub
  on a.subject_id = sub.id
left join type t
  on a.type_id = t.id
```

If you are unfamiliar with `JOIN` syntax, here is a great link:

[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: It's a personal project Remm, it isn't homework.  Ideally I wanted to pull a set number of the most recent entries and display them on the home page.  I could use PHP I just assumed using mysql could do it efficiently for me.

Excellent link on joins bluefeet, I'll give left join a try.